# Blender 3.5 file crash after increasing subdivisions

Tags: subdivision-surface, blend-files

I cranked up the subdivisions on a mesh in my scene and the file totally froze up - now any attempt at opening it will crash Blender. Is that scene just not workable anymore or is there a way to solve this?

Running on a 16” Macbook Pro with M1 Pro chip & 16GB. I increased the subdivisions using the scroll bar on the pop-up menu and it has been stuck ever since, so I don’t know the exact value. Clearly too much for my laptop to handle.

Comment: How much did you increase the subdivision? Does your PC have enough RAM to handle the increased geometry? Plz provide more details

Comment: Might be worth trying to opening it from Blender's file selector (File > Open...) with 'Load UI' turned off which you can do in the file selector's 'N' panel.

Comment: This is most likely a hardware issue, try and older version

Comment: Thank you for the responses! I was able to open the file by toggling Load UI (thank you John Eason), it still ran slow but from there I could lower max subdivisions in the render tab. Problem solved.